# elasticsearch & how can i search exact array element

Tags: elasticsearch

for example, I got three items like:

```
{"arr":["a", "b", "c"]},  
{"arr":["a", "b"]},  
{"arr":["a",  "c"]}
```

my search like this:

```
"query":{
    "bool":{
        "must":[  
            {
                "term":{
                    "arr":{
                        "value":"a"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "term":{
                    "arr":{
                        "value":"b"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "minimum_should_match": 2
    }
},
```

I just want to get ['a', 'b'] but also get ['a', 'b', 'c'].
I google a lot , but cannot find a way to solve this.
Is elasticsearch has this ability to do this?

Comment: Yes, but first share your mapping plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, but could be low in performance if you are looking for more complex data.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "arr": {
              "value": "a"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "arr": {
              "value": "b"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "script": {
            "script": "doc['arr'].length == 2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```